# Para las llaves foráneas, ¿este código es el mas eficiente? ¿Que otras formas existen?

Tags: sql

```
ALTER TABLE [Gral].[tbMunicipio]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dep_Id] FOREIGN KEY([dep_codigo])
REFERENCES [Gral].[tbDepartamento] ([dep_Codigo])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Gral].[tbMunicipio] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dep_Id]
GO
```

Comment: No de entiende tu pregunta ni a qué te refieres con eficiente, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: ¿Cuáles son los criterios que mides para determinar la eficiencia de una clave foránea en una tabla de una base de datos relacional?

Comment: Para la creación de llaves foráneas no necesitas buscar lo eficiente sino lo correcto.